# How to write algebraic expression to consist of given expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, substitution

Let's say I have following expression

$$ 
\alpha = \frac{R_s + R_r\cdot\frac{L^2_h}{L^2_r}}{L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}} 
$$

where following relationships holds
$$
L_s = L_{s\sigma} + L_h
$$
$$
L_r = L_{r\sigma} + L_h
$$

I have been looking for a way how to express the $\alpha$ with usage of following expressions

$$R_S = R_s$$
$$R_R = R_r\cdot\frac{L^2_s}{L^2_h}$$
$$L_L = L_{r\sigma}\cdot\frac{L^2_s}{L^2_h} + L_{s\sigma}\cdot\frac{L_s}{L_h}$$
$$L_M = L_s$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any connection between $L_s$,  $L_r$ and $L_h$ ?

Comment: You could do something like (taking the second term of the numerator)
$$
R_r \frac{L_h^2}{L_r^2} =
 R_r \frac{L_s^2}{L_s^2}  \frac{L_h^2}{L_h^2}  \frac{L_h^2}{L_r^2} 
=
 \underbrace{R_r \frac{L_s^2}{L_h^2}}_{=R_R}  \frac{L_h^2}{L_s^2}  \frac{L_h^2}{L_r^2} 
$$
But that's not really pretty ...

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. If you want to write $\alpha$ in terms of $R_S$, $R_R$, $L_L$, $L_M$, then I get 
$$\alpha=-\frac{R_R L_M^2 + R_S (L_L + L_M)^2}{L_L L_M (L_L + L_M)}$$
which becomes just a bit tidier if we define, say, $K_L:=1/L_L$ and $K_M:=1/L_M$:
$$\alpha=-\frac{R_R K_L^2  + R_S (K_L + K_M)^2}{K_L + K_M}$$